# React not rendering my image from web source

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Why is my code not rendering the image that I am trying to render?

Any help is appreciated, I've been stuck with this problem for some time now.

Code:

```
export default class Homepage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      images: [
        "https://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/m/v/Y/E/V/small-red-apple-hi.png",
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="gallery">
          {this.state.images.map(({ src, index }) => (
            <img key={index} src={src} width="250px" height="250 px" />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you are using `Array.map`. If you remove the curly brackets it will work properly.

```js
this.state.images.map((src, index) => (
```

For more details, check out the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Oh god... haha. I'm really tired it seems now. Thank you very much for the answer!